# Binary and WxPython

Tags: python, binary, wxpython

So I know WxPython and Binary(I spent all summer learning python). I was wondering if I could some example code of how I could use an input dialog and convert into binary to number or number to binary. I don't need anything long just something to refresh my brain as I'm just havent use python in a long time and want a refresher. Anything would be great.

Comment: Do you know how to use an input dialog? Do you know how to convert a string to an integer? Do you know how to format a number as binary? Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Yes its just been like three months since ive used it and dont remeber thats why im askign for a refresher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import wx
a = wx.App(redirect=False)
my_str = wx.GetTextFromUser("Enter A Number!")
base = {'x':16,'b':2,'o':8}.get(my_str[1].lower(),10)
int_val = int(my_str,base)
hex_str = hex(int_val)   
bin_str = bin(int_val)

msg = """
User Entered:%s
Int:%s
Hex:%s
Bin:%s"""%(my_str,int_val,hex_str,bin_str)
wx.MessageBox(msg)
```

something like that

Comment: Instead of the explicit check for the `0x` prefix, why not just use the `0` value for the base, which will take care of that automatically (and also take care of `0X`, and `0o` and `0b` prefixes, and anything else I might have forgotten)?

Comment: Also, even if you do use explicit bases, you don't need the `[2:]` for anything; `int('0x1234', 16)` is always going to give you the same thing as `int('1234', 16)`.

Comment: @raspberry.pi: That isn't a helpful comment. What line gives you a `NameError`? What's the full error and traceback? What other code have you written around this? (Obviously, if you don't have anything called `my_wx_text_ctrl`, you're going to get a `NameError` from this code.)

Comment: how would i turn that into a widget

Comment: there fixed it :) now its self contained :P @raspberry.pi I dont know what you are asking?

Comment: thank you what im wondering is why is there a b in all the converstions? thats not what my teacher tought me

Comment: `print 0b010101` , `print 0xFFa2` it is common programming convention to indicate the base of the number

Comment: Not to be a bother but is there a way to print that convertion in wx.messagebox or is that not possible?